# Unable to write in the Directory - Digital Ocean

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, permissions, chmod

I am trying to upload an image with post request and move it to a directory. I tried..

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$extension = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    
$generatedName = sha1(time().time());
$directory = '../public/uploads/imgs/'; // works
$fileName =  $generatedName . "." . $extension; // works

// 1
$file->move($directory, $fileName);
// 2
$file->move(base_path().$directory, $fileName);
```

At this point, I am receiving error:

> 1 Unable to write in the "../public/uploads/imgs" directory
>
> 2 Unable to write in the "var/www/laravel/public/uploads/imgs" directory

---

I thought it was caused by permissions but didn't help either.. I tried

```
sudo chmod 770 /var/www/laravel/public/uploads (also /imgs/
and
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/public/uploads
```

I also found something else to try but couldn't figure out what to write in username bit:

```
sudo chown username:www-data /var/www/laravel/public/uploads/
```

---

I am using NGINX on Digital Ocean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem with specific case of Digital Ocean.. First I tried...

```
 useradd -U -G www-data -m -c "deploy" deploybot
 chown deploybot:www-data /var/www/laravel
 chmod 2755 /var/www/laravel
```

Then..

```
 sudo usermod -aG www-data deploybot
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel/public/uploads
 sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

More info [here](http://deploybot.com/guides/deploy-a-laravel-app-to-digitalocean) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-can-t-seem-to-grant-myself-write-permissions-to-the-www-directory)

Comment: Do a `ps aux | grep nginx` in your console. Look for `nginx worker process` in the furtherest right column. Confirm if your first column at that line reads `www-data`

Comment: Yes it does. I have 4 of `worker process` with first column `www-data`

Comment: Alright the problem ain't with your server, it's in the code. Be right back writing an answer.

Comment: I solved it with the above code that I included in the answer

Answer (score 4):

Starting with your error messages:

**1. Unable to write in the "../public/uploads/imgs" directory**

By default, your nginx is pointing to the `public` folder of your laravel installation. `../public/uploads/imgs` will therefore resolve to `/var/www/laravel/public/uploads/imgs` which won't work if it doesn't have read permissions to the `laravel` folder.

*Normally, nginx should only have read access to your `public` folder.*

**2. Unable to write in the "var/www/laravel/public/uploads/imgs" directory**

The path is a relative one. It's absolute path is `/var/www/laravel/public/var/www/laravel/public/uploads/imgs` which won't exist by default.

Solution:

Replace these lines:

```
$directory = '../public/uploads/imgs/';
$file->move(base_path().$directory, $fileName);
```

With:

```
$directory = 'uploads/imgs/';
$file->move(public_path().$directory, $fileName);
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#paths

**Warning:** Do not give nginx write access to your `public` folder! If someone manages to upload & overwrite your `index.php`, your site will be compromised.

Comment: i can do that in my local and also can do that in my server 2012 as laravel host but cant do that with my linux cpanel server... all those 3 codes and laravel same version. i dont know why chmod -R ...../images run as 777  but image never  uploaded

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi It's best to verify your logs to check where the error is exactly. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors

Comment: strange think is that in cpanel i put my public folder in api.mydomain.com and other laravel files in root of my cpanel and when call public_http method it returned me /home/mydomain/laravel/images but i need /home/mydomain/api.mydomain.com/images so i catch it and solved

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this command to give write permissions to the `upload` directory and all it's subdirectories:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/public/uploads
```

Comment: Still getting the same errors.. This doesn't seem to help for both (1) and (2)

Answer (score 1):

Try first creating the directory with:

```
$directory_path = "...";//whatever you wish it to be

//if the directory doesn't exist already, it is created:
if (!file_exists($directory_path))
{
  mkdir($directory_path);
}
```

At first don't include the other code, just to see if you are able to actually create a directory. If it works and its there, try including the file there. Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: I tried it. I put print("A") inside the if but I forgot to include it in the first time. At the end, I included `$file->move($directory, $fileName);` however, I started receiving `Unable to write in the "../public/uploads/imgs" directory`

Comment: ok so if your getting the "Unable to write..." error, then almost certainly its permissions, though if you already changed it to writable as you said in your question, then I can't be sure. Maybe posting an inquiry in the forum of your webhosting provider, or even calling them should work, sadly it is tedious...

Comment: Ye, unfortunately `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/public/uploads` doesn't change anything :(

Comment: @senty I know that in CPanel, when I go into the file manager where I can see all my directories and files, the permissions code is in one of the columns and I can change them manually by clicking on them. That might work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use CPanel, I use nginx from digital ocean.. What may be the problem causing it? :/

Comment: Since I have never used nginx from digital ocean, I can't be sure. It could be that the settings are somewhere hidden, it could be that your permissions are blocked for some reason (maybe you are using free hosting that doesn't allow it). I can only guess. Your best bet would be to search if other users had similar problems online while using nginx. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please create target path imgs with proper permission rather without specific permission. Please check the following codes where you can give permission to imgs folder.

```
$destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/imgs/';

// Create folders if they don't exist
if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
   File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, $mode = 0755, true, true);
}
```

Where makeDirectory params are will clarified at [here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/147/creating-a-directory).

FYI, $mode would be 0775, 0777 ( thought it should not give it).

Answer (score 0):

sudo usermod -aG www-data deploybot\

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel/public/uploads

sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www

It works for me
Make sure change your user accordingly 
in this case it is deploybot